# String not updating in SSIS/C# with regex replacement

Tags: c#, .net, regex, ssis

I am trying to parse a super messy string in order to convert it to valid JSON (i.e "`":"[\"product1\",\"[\\\"product2\\\"\",\"\\\"[\\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"product3\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\\"]\\\"]\"]"`, etc.) in SSIS with a script component in .NET 4.7. The SSIS package runs, however, my code below is not performing any replacement to the string `jsonObj`. I cannot figure out why.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //set variables

    string jsonObj = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Row.UNSTRUCTUREDVARS.GetBlobData(0,Convert.ToInt32(Row.UNSTRUCTUREDVARS.Length)));

    string[] regExPattern = new string[] { "\\\\", "\\d\"\"", "\"\\[", "\"\"\\[", "\\]\"", "}}\"\"", "\"\"{", "}\"\"", ":\"{", "}\"", "\\]\"\"" };
    string[] replacePattern = new string[] { "", "\"", "[", "[", "]", "}}", "{", "}", ":{", "},", "]," };


    for (int i = 0; i<regExPattern.Length; i++)
    {

        Regex rgx = new Regex(regExPattern[i]);
        jsonObj = rgx.Replace(jsonObj, replacePattern[i]);

    }
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean when you say "my code below is not performing any replacement of the string jsonObj". Is the code itself not doing what you want? Assuming your code works, you are not assigning the value back to the row.

Comment: @JWeezy the problem is the regular expressions are not being applied to jsonObj when I call the replace function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RegEx code works, you are not assigning the value back to the row. So, the data is just going off into oblivion.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //set variables    
    string jsonObj = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Row.UNSTRUCTUREDVARS.GetBlobData(0,Convert.ToInt32(Row.UNSTRUCTUREDVARS.Length)));    
    string[] regExPattern = new string[] { "\\\\", "\\d\"\"", "\"\\[", "\"\"\\[", "\\]\"", "}}\"\"", "\"\"{", "}\"\"", ":\"{", "}\"", "\\]\"\"" };
    string[] replacePattern = new string[] { "", "\"", "[", "[", "]", "}}", "{", "}", ":{", "},", "]," };

    for (int i = 0; i<regExPattern.Length; i++)
    {    
        Regex rgx = new Regex(regExPattern[i]);
        jsonObj = rgx.Replace(jsonObj, replacePattern[i]);
    }

    Row.UNSTRUCTUREDVARS = jsonObj;
}
```